# c# json confusing behavior compared to wcf

Tags: c#, json

I am very new to json in c# and got some confusion.

Classes I have:

```
public class Account
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public bool Status { get; set; }

    public Customer OwnerCustomer { get; set; }
}

public class Customer
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public DateTime BirthDate { get; set; }
}
```

Deserializing response as below:

```
List<object> tmpList = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<object[]>(productJsonString).ToList();
```

Now questions:

1. No properties of original class available, below code displays:

   foreach (PropertyInfo pi in item.GetType().GetProperties())
   {
     Debug.WriteLine(pi.Name);
   };

Type
Item
Item
HasValues
First
Last
Count
Parent
Root
Next
Previous
Path

2. Binding List to Grid, only displays root object, inner object is not displayed.

In WCF, it was enough to mark Class and Properties with DataContract, DataMember, KnownType and serialization is done as expected. Sorry, I did not got JSON deserialize my object to client side as expected.

Thanks for your time.

Comment: Deserialize it directly to the type you want. List<Account> tmpList = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<Account>>(productJsonString);

Comment: Are you adding a reference to NewtonSoft.Json?  Following works fine for me         List<Account> tmpList = new List<Account>(2);
        tmpList.Add(acct1);
        tmpList.Add(acct2);
        string productJsonString = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(tmpList);
        tmpList.Clear();
        tmpList = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Account[]>(productJsonString).ToList();`

Comment: As Stephen mentioned, you have to specify the "root" object in the generic parameter.  If you're not able to figure that out, I'd suggest you post your JSON string as well for help on that.  DataContract, etc isn't generally required if you're using JSON.Net. If you're using one of the DataContract serializers built into .Net, it's needed.

Comment: Thanks for your answers. You are correct, if I specify root object, then it works. However, I want not to share my Business Objects at client side.

Comment: Then look at [Querying JSON with dynamic](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/QueryJsonDynamic.htm) or [Querying JSON with LINQ](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/QueryJsonLinq.htm) or [Querying JSON with SelectToken](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/QueryJsonSelectToken.htm).  Of course, you lose all type safety.